# System.Exception: Shape file not found: [PATH]

Tags: c#, arcgis, uwp

When this method is invoked I get the following stack trace when it reaches OpenAsync():

> System.Exception: Shape file not found:
>   C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\shapes\TOTALMAP\OH_Line_6600v_Expired.shp    at
>   RuntimeCoreNet.Interop.HandleException(Boolean retVal)    at
>   RuntimeCoreNet.CoreFeatureSource.FromShapefile(String filename)    at
>   Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.ShapefileTable.OpenAsync(String filename)
>   at ShapeSQLiteGISDemo.MainPage.d__3.MoveNext()

I have a .dbf and .shx file in the same folder with the same name and I've been running Visual Studio in Administrator Mode.

```
private async void ImportShapes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get path from file picker
            var picker = new FileOpenPicker { SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop };
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".shp");
            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            //convert folder contents to a ShapefileTable
            var shapefile = await ShapefileTable.OpenAsync(file.Path);

            //save object to database
            _DatabaseConnection.Insert(shapefile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        //call a method that loads shapes from the database
        LoadDatabaseOntoMap();
    }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the *.shp* as associated file type in *Declarations* in *package.appxmanifest* file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that with Store and UWP apps the .shp file has to be moved to a folder in the local storage before the application can open it.

Will set as the accepted answer if this solves the problem.

EDIT: This is indeed the case, because I was choosing a single file with the the file picker I only had access to that one file. To get multiple files I used the folder picker and filtered away any files that weren't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an app like notepad to open the file by pasting in the path:

> C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\shapes\TOTALMAP\OH_Line_6600v_Expired.shp

Does the app open the file?

Are there other examples of shape files that do open? Could this file simply be corrupted?

Comment: The same issue still occurs when passed a string literal.

Comment: Try using an app like notepad to open the file by pasting in the path: C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\shapes\TOTALMAP\OH_Line_6600v_Expired.shp

Does the app open the file?

Comment: File Explorer confirms the path is valid and that it leads to the correct file.

Comment: Are there other examples of shape files that do open? Could this file simply be corrupted?

Comment: I have a folder full of confirmed working shape files and they all have this issue.